# Can I use a tourist visa appointment at VFS to apply for a short-term spousal visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, spouses

I’m married to an EU National but live in the UK (I’m not a British or EU citizen). In theory I should be able to apply for a short-term spousal visa when we travel to Spain together, but there are no appointments available (at all) due to a shortage of appointment spots allocated to VFS.

There are bots that offer notifications when slots open up, but only for “tourism” visas.

On the VFS website they make a distinction between tourism and spousal visas, so I’m worried that if I book an appointment spot for a tourism visa I won’t be able to get a spousal visa. The difference might be important because the spousal visa requires fewer documents, so if I prepare for that I may not have everything for a tourism visa.

Can I use a tourist visa appointment at VFS to apply for a short term spouse visa?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a EU National Family Member, you have the right to skip the processors (here BLS) entirely and get an appointment directly to the consulate, also skipping the processor's fee.

The [London consulate](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visados-para-familiares-de-ciudadanos-de-la-Union.aspx) states

> To book an appointment please send an email to the e-mail address cog.londres.viscp@maec.es. In the SUBJECT you must specify “EU/EEA family member Schengen visa appointment"

You also need to submit documents along that appointment request

For the London jurisdiction, you may also walk in without an appointment at the BLS office, but you will need to pay the processor's fee (which is 15.45€)

> It is also possible submit the application in BLS International without the need for an appointment.
> the charge for services rendered must be paid.

If you want to skip the fee, you may contact cog.manchester.citasvis@maec.es in Manchester and cog.edimburgo.vis@maec.es in Edinburgh to get a direct appointment

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to Spain, then you can apply for a visa for family members **directly** at the responsible consulate (Edinburgh, London, Manchester).

The **Required documents** portion gives a detailed list of what is required and the application form can be downloaded there.

The **Procedure** portion makes no mention of an appointment requirement for either the Visa Application Centre or consulate.

---

> [Visas for family members of a citizen of the Union - Spanish Consulate, London](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visados-para-familiares-de-ciudadanos-de-la-Union.aspx)
> **Procedure**
> **This Consular Office is competent to accept visa applications** from third-country nationals residing in the consular district  who are travelling to Spain as their main destination.
>
> Who can apply for a visa: Applications must be submitted in person. If the applicant is a minor, the application must be submitted by their legal representatives.
>
> Place of submission: EU FAMILY MEMBER VISA APPLICANTIONS must be submited in person  at BLS INTERNATIONAL CENTER **or at the Consulate**.
>
> BLS INTERNATIONAL
> Spain Visa Application Centre
> 20 St Andrew Street, London EC4A 3AG.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visas for family members of a citizen of the Union  - Spanish Consulate, London](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visados-para-familiares-de-ciudadanos-de-la-Union.aspx)

Comment: I would like to vote to delete this answer because it’s a duplicate or repeating the above answer in nature